# Что использовать для создания кастомных View с динамической прорисовкой?

Tags: android, customview, glsurfaceview

Собираюсь создать кастомный View в котором будет что то вроде анимированной прорисовки. Что лучше использовать для этого SurfaceView или Обычный View с прицепленным AsyncTask(который и будет вызывать прорисовку в нужный момент времени)

Comment: SurfaceView используйте, он больше подходит!

Comment: @KirillStoianov ок бро, попробую поюзать сюрфэйс